# Is it possible to add weight to images in a generator?

Tags: javascript, random

I wish to make a random image generator (which is working fine), however, I was wondering is there a way to add weight to certain images which won't appear as much as others?

I have attached the code below:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()

myimages[1]="Blue_Car.png"
myimages[2]="Red_Car.png"
myimages[3]="White_Car.png"
myimages[4]="Black_Car.png"


var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()


function confirmRefresh() {
var okToRefresh = confirm("Do you really want to refresh the page?");
if (okToRefresh)
    {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10);
    }
}

</script>
<input type="button" value="Generate a new player" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">


</script>
</a></p>
```

I do have a SMALL amount of knowledge regarding JavaScript, however, I'm no pro.

Comment: what do you mean by weight? you want a 10kb image to be 100kb?

Comment: He means `probability` I guess. I'm already writing a solution, give me 2 minutes...

Comment: Like, increase and decrease the chances of an image appearing. For instance, I don't want the black car to appear as much as the red car. Sorry, I used the wrong term I guess?

Comment: Yes, probability. And thank you! Take all the time you like! :)

Comment: Simplest way is simply populating the array multiple times with the value and then grab a random element from the array.

Comment: So this for example?                                              myimages[1]="Blue_Car.png"
myimages[2]="Red_Car.png"
myimages[3]="White_Car.png"
myimages[5]="Black_Car.png"                 myimages[6]="White_Car.png"                 myimages[7]="White_Car.png" If I wanted to the white car to have a higher chance to appear more than the others cars? But can I actually use duplicate code? And use the same path/image source?

Comment: If you're doing a light preference, then adding the same thing one or two more times wouldn't hurt, and would keep your code a bit cleaner. Wouldn't recommend it though if you were to add more than a few extra elements. After that it's just harder to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myimages=new Array();
myimages[0]="Blue_Car.png";
myimages[1]="Red_Car.png";
myimages[2]="White_Car.png";
myimages[3]="Black_Car.png";
// myimages[4] = ...

// All values summed up must equal 1
var probabilities=new Array();
probabilities[0]=0.1;  // 10%
probabilities[1]=0.1;  // 10%
probabilities[2]=0.25; // 25%
probabilities[3]=0.55; // 55%
// probabilities[4] = ... (also need to change the other probability values)

function getImage() {
    var rand = Math.random();
    var probabilitiy_sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {
        probabilitiy_sum += probabilities[i];
        if(rand <= probabilitiy_sum ) {
            return myimages[i];
        }
    }
    return myimages[myimages.length];
}

// Just for testing:
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML += getImage() + "<br />";
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

Comment: How would I get the images to appear instead of text?

Comment: Use `document.write('<img src="' + getImage() +'" border=0>');`

Comment: So, I could just copy and paste this and it should work?

Comment: OK, I copied and pasted it and it works pretty great! Two images appear which I'm happy with, is there a possible way to add an extra image?

Comment: Of course. Add a new row to `myimages` and one to `probabilities`. Just keep in mind that all `probabilities` summed up must equal `1`.

Comment: Ok thank you so much man! Means a lot! However, one question. The values of the probabilities in the array does 0.1 mean that image has a higher chance of being shown? Also what is the highest value I could add to make it so that an image appears like in one in a hundred?

Comment: Use the percentage. `100% probability` => `1.0` or `47% probability` => `0.47`. If you set the value of one image to `1.0` (`100%`) and all others to `0.0` (`0%`), only this single picture will be used. Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: So where you have stated "// All values together should equal 1" I could potentially do                                                     probabilities[0]=0.17;
probabilities[1]=0.23;
probabilities[2]=0.38;
probabilities[3]=0.22; ???

Comment: That's correct. (One in a hundred is `1%`, so use the probability `0.01`.)

Comment: Oh wow dude! How do I accept your answer? Also do you have a Skype? I haven't got money at the moment, however, when I do I will reward you as promised. :)

Comment: Haha, no thanks. I will not take money for something that was fun to program :D This is how you can accept the answer: [Accepting Answers: How does it work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/282753)

Comment: You sure? I'll happily pay you? Also I need 15 reputation so I can upvote your answer.

Comment: I clicked the tick button.

Comment: Also would it be possible for you to show me how to add a row? Because I've used grow a row but only with a .JSON file and struggled.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer :) I'm sure I don't want to get paid. It took me 3 minutes to program :) To add another image, just do the same like I have done to add the images: below `myimages[3]` add `myimages[4] = "xy.png";` and below `probabilities[3]` add `probabilities[4]=0.xy;`.

Comment: No haha, I know how to do that. I meant to generate more than one image when the program is executed

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry. Just execute `document.write` twice: `document.write('<img src="' + getImage() +'" border=0>'); document.write('<img src="' + getImage() +'" border=0>');`. The function `getImage()` always returns a new image.

Comment: Actually, I have like 6-10 images being generate all at once, how do I limit this to three images?

Comment: Now I'm getting several different outcomes and the number of images vary from 2, 1, 3, 5 etc. How can I just do it so 3 images are generated every time I reload the page?

Comment: Just add that three `document.write` lines below my code (instead of the `Just for testing` thing). If that does not work, please send me an email with your current (not-working) code using the contact form on my website (http://www.bytehamster.com/?q=contact) and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

To extend @ByteHamster's response (accept his, not mine), you can do the same thing with an array of objects to easier keep track of the possibilities.

```js
var myimages = [{
  image: "Blue_Car.png",
  probability: 0.1
}, {
  image: "Red_Car.png",
  probability: 0.1
}, {
  image: "White_Car.png",
  probability: 0.25
}, {
  image: "Black_Car.png",
  probability: 0.55
}];

function getImage() {
  var rand = Math.random();
  var probabilitiy_sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myimages.length; i++) {
    probabilitiy_sum += myimages[i].probability;
    if (rand <= probabilitiy_sum) {
      return myimages[i].image;
    }
  }
  return myimages[myimages.length].image;
}

// Just for testing:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML += getImage() + "<br />";
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

Comment: Good idea. You forgot to change the last return statement :) `myimages[myimages.length]` should be `myimages[myimages.length].image`. The program should never reach that line, I added it just to be sure that there is a fallback picture if something goes wrong (eg sum of percentages not `100%`)

Comment: Thanks for the code. Right now it just shows the url. How can I show the picture behind the url?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would just to be to increase the length of your array, and then add the images with more probability to hit more times, and the images with less probability less times. You can use a for loop for each.

```
for (i=0;i<15;i++) {
    myimages[i] = "Blue_Car.png";
}
for (i=15;i<40;i++) {
    myimages[i] = "Red_Car.png";
}
for (i=40;i<80;i++) {
    myimages[i] = "White_Car.png";
}
for (i=80;i<100;i++) {
    myimages[i] = "Black_Car.png";
}
```

Comment: So this for example? myimages[1]="Blue_Car.png" myimages[2]="Red_Car.png" myimages[3]="White_Car.png" myimages[5]="Black_Car.png" myimages[6]="White_Car.png" myimages[7]="White_Car.png" If I wanted to the white car to have a higher chance to appear more than the others cars? But can I actually use duplicate code? And use the same path/image source?  Also what type of loop?

Comment: Edited answer with example

Comment: The numbers after the i, what do they represent? The likelihood of that image appearing?

Comment: So in my example your array length will be 100. Blue Car is added 15 times, and so if you use your original random selector it will have a 15% chance of hitting.  Red Car is added 25 times, so it has a 25% chance of hitting. White Car is added 40 times, so it has a 40% chance of hitting. Black Car is added 20 times so it has a 20% chance of hitting. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Your code generates huge arrays. Not sure if it is good for performance.

Comment: Its an easy way. Probably better ways out there.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer, but I'll post mine anyway.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var counter = 0;  // this is just to show that something happens when you randomly get the same car as the previous car.  
function random_imglink() {
  var myimages = [
    {weight: 3,  url: "http://insideevs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/bollare-bluecar.jpg"}, // blue
    {weight: 10, url: "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-UKeEILt_8nw/UZOCIEMrMVI/AAAAAAAAAvI/X5i-HaJRnTc/s400/red+car10.jpg"},  // red
    {weight: 5,  url: "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02661/Audi-A5-Sportback_2661284b.jpg"}, // white
    {weight: 2,  url: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mojnxHJlWVA/UZ1KShiKMeI/AAAAAAAAHMo/oO7qMo7PJq4/s400/Best-Black-Car-2009_j2bq.gif"} // black
  ];
  // calculate total weigt
  // this example: totalWeight = 20
  // Then we search a random number from 0 to 19.  0,1,2 belongs to blue; 3 to 12 is red; 13 to 17 is white; 18 to 19 is black
  // we add min and max range to the image object, so we can easily return the good one.
  var totalWeight = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<myimages.length; i++) {
    myimages[i].min = totalWeight;
    myimages[i].max = totalWeight + myimages[i].weight - 1;  // example: if the first weight is 3; the max is 3-1 = 2
    totalWeight += myimages[i].weight;
  }
  var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalWeight);
  for (var i=0; i<myimages.length; i++) {
    if (ry >=  myimages[i].min && ry <=  myimages[i].max) {
      var index = i;  // we've got a winner
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = '<img src="' + myimages[index].url + '">';
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counter++;
}
window.onload = function() {
  random_imglink();
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="New random car" onClick="random_imglink()">
<div id="counter"></div>
<div id="image"></div>
```