# Random image with probability with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I have a question about generating a random image with different probabilities. I've googled, I found one comparable question ([Is it possible to add weight to images in a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696298/is-it-possible-to-add-weight-to-images-in-a-generator%29)) but this code doesn't work for me.

I'm practicing on a free website now, so I can't use PHP. I only can use HTML. Someone told me, if I can use html, I can use Javascript too.

Can anyone help me? I'm trying this code now, but it doesn't work:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array();
myimages[1]="http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/215.png"
myimages[2]="http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/204.png"
myimages[3]="http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/198.png"
myimages[4]="http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/313.png"

var probabilities=new Array();
probabilities[1]=0.4;  
probabilities[2]=0.3;  
probabilities[3]=0.2; 
probabilities[4]=0.1;

function getImage() {
    var rand = Math.random();
    var probabilitiy_sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {
        probabilitiy_sum += probabilities[i];
        if(rand <= probabilitiy_sum ) {
            return myimages[i];
        }
    }
    return myimages[myimages.length];
}

</script>
</a></p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use JavaScript for this. There are several problems with your code.

Most significant of which are **probability array should be sorted in increasing order of values and JavaScript array indices start at zero not one**.

Here is the modified working code.

```
var images = [
    { probability: .4, url: "http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/215.png"},
    { probability: .3, url: "http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/204.png"},
    { probability: .2, url: "http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/198.png"},
    { probability: .1, url: "http://eredivisie-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Badges/313.png"}
];

// it has to be in increasing order of probabilities
images.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.probability - b.probability;
});

function getImageUrl(images) {
    var rand = Math.random();
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
        sum += images[i].probability;
        if(rand <= sum ) {
            return images[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the test code for the same algorithm.

```
(function () {
    function getImageUrl(images) {
        var rand = Math.random();
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
            sum += images[i].probability;
            if(rand <= sum ) {
                return i; //modified to return index
            }
        }
    }
    var occurrences = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        occurrences[getImageUrl(images)]++;
    }
    console.log(occurrences);
})();
```

Test results for 100 runs of the method,

```
//count of times images occur, indices are in increasing order of probabilities
[8, 23, 36, 33]
[8, 18, 37, 37]
[12, 25, 29, 34]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it doesnt work. I get a blank page.